# echo into '/proc/filename' gives "Operation Not Permitted" error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, module, kernel, proc

Platform: Ubuntu 5.15.0-43-generic.

I have written a loadable kernel module to create a file under `/proc` called `testproc`. The kernel module loads perfectly and created the `/proc/testproc`. The permissions on `/proc/testproc` are 0666 and owned by root. I am logged in as root for all operations.

I have implemented the read and write handler in my kernel module and they get called too.

When I run the command

```
echo "Hello" > /proc/testproc
```

the error seen is

```
bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

I am using the call

```
proc_create("testproc", 0666, NULL, &procfsFuncs)
```

to create the entry under `/proc`

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: "I have implemented the read and write handler in my kernel module and they get called too." - How have you checked that write handler is actually called if your `echo` fails?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my (trivial) mistake. I was expecting a non-zero result from copy_from_user(), when in reality copy_from_user returns 0 on success.